# Couchbase Sink Kafka Connector Ignore Error and Continue

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I created a sink connector from Kafka to Couchbase.
It writes all events to Couchbase successfully until an event that has empty key came.

It stuck at that point with failure on the task.

Error in the connector task:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception

Caused by: com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException: Id cannot be null or empty\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException.fromMessage(InvalidArgumentException.java:28)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.util.Validators.notNullOrEmpty(Validators.java:70)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.util.Validators.notNullOrEmpty(Validators.java:78)\n\t... 35 more\n"
```

I want to ignore that error and continue with the other events.

I try these configs but it didn't work.

```
"errors.tolerance": "all",
"errors.log.enable": true,
"errors.log.include.messages": true,
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the [official Couchbase Kafka connector](https://docs.couchbase.com/kafka-connector/current/index.html), or are you writing your own?

Comment: For anyone else who comes along, there's a [discussion of this topic on the Couchbase Forum](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-ignore-errors-in-sink-kafka-connector/35762).